# Stop the "wet look" of top coat on grey wood

Tags: finishing, door

I am almost done with an interior office door project.The doors are massive (8ft tall) Fir doors that I grayed with vinegar and steel wool. My wife loves the color and all the testing I have done result in a more "brown" look as when I apply the wood takes a "wet look". I was considering if I should go to a wax like Mylands and wanted to see if anyone had a recommendation for a way to keep the grey color but also provide a bit of a sealant for the wood. They are doors so moisture and etc aren't a problem but they will get a lot of touch I am sure.

Comment: Take a look at the test piece to see the effect of Flat out Flat. It has been drying for 6 hours now. In addition to getting darker you can see that it is now more brown that grey. Thoughts?

https://photos.app.goo.gl/394C9boMU5wI58hJ3

Comment: Well I would describe the wood *above* the test patch as flat-out flat, not the wood below! It's hard to be sure from just one photo but there certainly appears to be added sheen. This unfortunately is not that uncommon with matt/flat finishes as there's no standard for mattness.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I wouldn't use wax for anything I wanted to actually be protected.

There are a couple of things you can use here but I think what you'll end up picking is waterbased poly, for the same reason it's chosen by many for driftwood projects — minimal colour change.

While barnwood and driftwood projects are often finished matt I'd use a semi-matt or satin here.

Comment: I am currently testing flat out flat from general finishes. I will post a picture when the second coat is fully dried. This cold snap makes it a non starter for me to top coat the doors anyway.

Comment: Here's why I'd have gone with a semi-matt or satin finish rather than a matt, *The increased matting agents used to create "flat look" cause this wood finish to have less clarity, show fingerprints more and provide slightly less durability than High Performance.*